# How would I include a slidshow in my Rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, web, slideshow, carousel

Hello I am working a basic rails app, and I want to include a welcome page with a slideshow. How would I implement this in a Rails app? I am new to Rails, and I tried using Jquery, but it didn't work. I am also using bootstrap on my website.The problem is that the images wont load and I only see the arrow buttons and no images.
Thanks! Here is my code,

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
</script>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item"><img src='pictwo.png'></div>
    <div class="item"><img src='pictone.png'></div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap incudes one, as well as provides examples on its usage - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel.

Comment: oh sorry. I just edited my question. I found that, but I am having problems with it. The images wont load and I just get the arrows.

Comment: Switch `<img src='pictwo.png'>` to `<%= image_tag 'pictwo.png' %>`.

Comment: oh wow!! thanks! it worked.. Do you know how I can resize the images? They look huge!

Comment: You can do `<%= image_tag 'pictwo.png' , size: '50x50' %>` (or whatever). More options can be found here - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag. This is only a partial measure, as it only adjusts the displayed size, it would be better to modify the source files.

Comment: Hey. I ran into another problem, that I could'nt solve. can you check it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683158/why-wont-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-slide